# Prove that $x^2 - y^2 < x^2 + y^2 + 2xy \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

This is a basic question in proving mathematical statements. One of the ways(not necessarily correct) is
\begin{gather}
x^2 - y^2 < x^2 + y^2 + 2xy \\
\implies 2y^2 + 2xy > 0 \\ 
\implies y^2 + xy > 0 \\
\implies y\cdot(y + x) > 0 \\
\implies y > 0 \land x + y > 0
\end{gather}
Suppose if I prove that $y > 0$ and $x + y > 0 \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and use the above fact to hence infer that $x^2 - y^2 < x^2 + y^2 + 2xy \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is true. Am I wrong?

Should I also prove that given $y > 0 \land x + y > 0 \implies x^2 - y^2 < x^2 + y^2 + 2xy$ in addition to the work done above?

**Edit**
I wanted to prove this on $\mathbb{Z}^+$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}$. Apologise for the mistake.

Comment: You cannot prove it. It is equivalent to $0 < 2 y(x+y)$, which does *not* hold for all integers.

Comment: Or even more directly, take $(x,y)=(-2,1)$ as a counterexample.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, or just let $y=0$. (Note, all three initial comments were made before the edit changing $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$.)

Comment: @MartinR Dietrich Burde I apologise for not stating the problem accurately. I have mentioned in the edit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having proven that the initial inequality is equivalent to "$y>0$ and $x+y>0$" suffices, since the latter is true for all $x,y\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$.

I'd suggest you to use the symbol $\iff$ instead of $\implies$ here. This may always be done if the lines may also be read from bottom to top. This allows you to skip proving the reverse direction.

Also, here's a different approach:
$$x^2-y^2<x^2+2xy+y^2\iff (x-y)(x+y)<(x+y)^2\iff x-y<x+y \iff y>0,$$
which is true.

Comment: This is then like saying if $p \implies T$ then p is true, right? here the tautology being $y > 0 \land x+ y > 0 \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Comment: No! You need to have $p\iff T$ in order to conclude that $p$ holds true. The implication $p\implies T$ is always true, even if $p$ is false. This is why I invited you to use $\iff$ instead of $\implies$ here.

Comment: Got it. I will remember it the next time. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your basic idea is OK, but to get a proper proof, you need to run the implications the other way.  That is

$$x,y\gt0\implies y(x+y)\gt0\implies2y^2+2xy\gt0\implies x^2-y^2\lt x^2+y^2+2xy$$

(Also, the final implication in the OP, $y(y+x)\gt0\implies y\gt0\land x+y\gt0$, isn't really correct in general; what's true is that $y(y+x)\gt0$ implies $y$ and $y+x$ are either both positive or both negative.)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of to prove this is the following:

Since $x$ and $y$ are positive, $2xy$ is positive and thus the following holds.

$$ xx + yy < xx + 2xy + yy $$

Since $y$ is positive, the following holds.

$$ xx - yy < xx + yy $$

Thus, by transitivity of $<$ we have the following, as desired.

$$ xx - yy < xx + yy $$

---

The way you proved it works as well, but you have the implication arrows facing the wrong way.

$$ 0 < y \;\;\text{and}\;\; 0 < x + y $$

The product of two positive numbers is positive.

$$ 0 < y \cdot (x + y)$$

$$ 0 < xy + yy $$

Doubling preserves the inequality (because $x \mapsto 2x$ is strictly increasing).

$$ 0 < 2yy + 2xy $$

Adding a constant $xx - yy$ to both sides preserves the inequality.

$$ xx - yy < xx + 2x + yy $$